# angularjs controller giving Unknown Provider for $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular js, I am creating a test app to understand the flow, however when I am trying to use $stateParams then my controller is not loading, in console I am getting the error message which is redirecting me to https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0= where I am able to see this

> Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider

My controller looks like below

```
angular.module('NerdCtrl', []).controller('NerdController', ["$scope","$stateParams", "Nerd", function($scope, $stateParams, Nerd) {
        $scope.getAll = function() {
            Nerd.get().success(function(data, res) {
                $scope.nerds = data
            })
        }

        $scope.saveNerd = function(nerd){
           Nerd.create(nerd).success(function(data, res){
              console.log(data) 
           });
        }
        $scope.getNerd = function(){
            console.log($stateParams.id)
        }



    }]);
```

Nerd is a factory which I have created for services

If I am not including $stateParams then everything is working fine as expected.

Comment: `$stateParams` is part of `ui.router`, so it must be injected into your module.

Comment: Do you include ui-router? If yes, inject them in dependencies of NerdCtrl.

Comment: Add  angular.module('NerdCtrl', [''ui.router'']) along with <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

Comment: thanks guys I was missing `ui.router`