# Injecting $stateParams for angular unit testing testing with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Lets start with the controller code:

```
angular
.module('hc.hotelContent')
.controller('NameLocationController', nameLocationCtrlFn); //Todo change hotelDataService
nameLocationCtrlFn.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'hotelDataService'];

  function nameLocationCtrlFn($stateParams, hotelDataService) {
       var vm = this,
       hotelId = $stateParams.hotelId;
       vm.Keys = {
        Name: 'Name',
        Street: 'Street',
        City: 'City',
        State: 'State',
        Zip: 'Zip',
        Country: 'Country'
    }
}
```

i do have some more code but its irellevant logic, my tests work fine when i do not inject the $stateParmas to the controller.
**so heres the Test file:**

```
    describe('nameLocation component Controller', function () {
    var $controller,
            hotelDataServiceMock,
           stateParams,
            hotelId = "4611";
Keys = {
        Name: 'Name',
        Street: 'Street',
        City: 'City',
        State: 'State',
        Zip: 'Zip',
        Country: 'Country'
    }//@
    beforeEach(module('hc.hotelContent'));
        beforeEach(module('hc.app.core'));
        beforeEach(inject(injectFn));
       function injectFn(_$controller_, $stateParams, _hotelDataService_) {
            $controller = _$controller_;
            stateParams = $stateParams;

            hotelDataServiceMock = _hotelDataService_;
        } //controller injection fn

        function initCtrl() {
            controller = $controller('NameLocationController', {
                $stateParams: stateParams,
                hotelDataService: hotelDataServiceMock
            });
        }
describe('inserting a new hotel', function () {
        it('should populate Keys object', function () {
            var controller = initCtrl();
            expect(controller.Keys).toEqual(Keys);
        });
   }
}
```

im getting the Unknown Provider error. which has nothing to yet with my controller, all im doing in the controller is getting the variable set to the $stateParams variable.
how do i work with this injection?
my karma.conf file is configured to load jquery,angular,ui-router,mocks in this particular order and after that all the js and html

edit: i did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059759/angularjs-controller-giving-unknown-provider-for-stateparams) this post before but im using ui-router in my main app module, so ive added beforeEach(module('hc.app')); to the code but still nothing

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar issue testing $stateParams in a directive:

Try injecting `$state`,

Then you can use:
`$state.go('namedurl', {your_params_here})`
`$rootScope.$digest()` or $apply in your controller

Which will update the `$stateParams`. If you try injecting `$stateParams` as a mock with a provider they just get overwritten by the $state service.

Comment: I love how simple this solution is and how little you have to know about angular plumbing to get this to work. This really helps keep your tests simple.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that in `injectFn` your parameter name `$stateParams` doesn't match the variable you referring to (`_$stateParams_`)?  `_$stateParams_` is undefined in `injectFn`.

If that doesn't work, do you have ui-router injected into your module as well, and has that module been loaded in your test?  There was a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059759/angularjs-controller-giving-unknown-provider-for-stateparams).

If you want to just test that the controller uses `$stateParams.hotelId`, you could also mock out `$stateParams` with something like this:

```
function injectFn(_$controller_, _hotelDataService_, $provide) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    hotelDataServiceMock = _hotelDataService_;
    $provide.value('$stateParams', {
        hotelId: 'someId',
    });
}

function initCtrl() {
    return $controller('NameLocationController', {
         hotelDataService: hotelDataServiceMock,
    });
}
```

Comment: no it was just a type that ive changed. the ui router is injected but to another module

Comment: angular.module('hc.app', [
        'hc.app.core',
        'hc.app.shared',
        'hc.hotelContent',
        'hc.templateHtml',
        'ngMdIcons',
        'ngMaterial',
        'ui.router'
    ]);

Comment: Edited- clarified that you'll have to _load_ a module that has ui-router as a dependency.  (`beforeEach(module('hc.app'));`).  I also added a way to mock out $stateParams.

Comment: did it, still nothing, i want to use stateParams and not provide it since the value is passed by the router and will contain more params later on